# Storing and retrieving data as JSON string with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity

I am trying to store an object as JSON. Then, convert it back from JSON string to an object with Entity Framework Core 3 using C#.

I have the following 2 model classes:

```
public class A
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // more properties

    // I want to store the data as json.
    public CustomObject Object { get; set; }
}

public class CustomObject
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int[] ItemIds { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then in my `DbContext` I added the following

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<A>.Property(x => x.Object).HasConversion(
         v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore }),
         v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(v, new JsonSerializerSettings { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore })
            );
}
```

However, when the app run I get the following error

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The property 'Object.ItemIds' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'int[]' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.'

That error occurs when I try to set the entity in a generic class like this

```
Repository = context.Set<A>();
```

How can I correctly convert JSON string to an object and an object back to a JSON string with Entity Framework Core?

Comment: Can you include the statement that causes that exception to be thrown?

Comment: @devNull I updated the question to show where. It happenn when `context.Set<A>()` is called

Comment: You don't by chance have a `DbSet<CustomObject>` in your context do you?

Comment: I don’t.  I have DbSet<A> listed in the DbContext

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that EF is added the complex types by default "or something around these lines". To ignore it, I added the following and it worked

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Ignore<CustomObject>();
    // ...
}
```